# Is it possible to access json data from another domain after authentication?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, authentication

Is there any way to authenticate an API which is in another domain using javascript? If so, is it possible to access it using json data?

I have tried the following code, but it returns as "401 unauthorized" even the username and password is correct.

```
$.ajax
    ({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      data: '{}',
      beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
          xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
      },
      success: function (responseData){
          console.log(responseData);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider adding some more information on what you are trying to do, what you have tried so far, some research you may have done, so that people can understand what you are talking about.